# Using scan.nextLine() for Cyrillic

Tags: java

I don't know how to read Cyrillic or any other language except English from the console. I tried to do this:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in, "UTF_16");

String input = scan.nextLine();
```

But it keeps waiting for me to enter even though I already entered the text.

Comment: You can't do this on windows, the command line on windows is character orientated, so it fails displaying and receiving non ascii characters

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the **UTF_16** by **UTF-8**...

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in, "UTF-8");

        String input = scan.nextLine();
        String myString = "some cyrillic text";
        byte[] russianBytes = input.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"); 
        String valueConverted = new String(russianBytes, "UTF-8"); 
        System.out.println(valueConverted);

    }
```

this print takes ***Илия Камбуров*** and print it properly

Comment: This is my output when i test it:

Enter the text: Илия Камбуров

���� ��������

I am using NetBeans IDE 8.1 (Build 201510222201).

Comment: I don't know how to see this but i tried to run the program with cmd and it didn't work.

Comment: Try getting the bytes back and forward I update the answer.... if this don't work then you could try printing to a file rather then System.out

Comment: I tried the last code it didn't work. I tried to print "abvабв123" in file and the result was "abv???123". The problem might be in Windows settings or Local settings .... I don't know.